# How would it feel for a woman to be placed into a male body? [physiology only]

Tags: biology, sex

There are plenty of [sex differences in human physiology](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sex_differences_in_human_physiology): Body composition, skeleton, hormones, sexual organs, sensory systems, etc. My question is:

**How would it *feel* for a woman to be placed into a male body and what difficulties she would face when it comes to physiology?**

Basically, I want to know if walking, eating, talking, and other normal everyday activities will feel the same or will need some readjustment period. Will differences in hormonal status have noticeable physiological effects? I also wonder if the consummation of marriage is possible.

***When possible I would like the answers to focus on what would feel different and in what way.*** For example, an answer may suggest that walking will become harder because of the changed centre of gravity and for a while this woman in a male body will be moving like a drunk person (not sure if this is correct).

*Notes:*

1. 'Placed into a male body' can be understood as a soul of a genetically XX woman placed into a genetically XY male body (it is a miracle that does not need to be explained).  Please assume that the female soul and the male body are compatible and there are no big problems with body functions. Some things may feel weird or different, but everything works fine.
2. Psychological difficulties (including adjustment to a new gender role) are out of the scope of this question. Please do not concern yourselves with them. *If physiological changes (e.g. hormones) cause distinctly different psychological responses it is okay to include them.*
3. While there are some differences between male and female brains, those that would make the premise impossible can be discarded. Please also assume that the female soul has complete and 'natural' control over the body and does not need to relearn how to walk, eat, talk, etc.
4. If it matters, the woman is an adult, the male body is also a fully developed male body.
5. The woman has her memories intact.
6. Please assume that the height and weight of the new male body are approximately the same as the original female body.

---

**Update**:

I understand the theory of sex differences. I am looking for approximations of how it would actually feel to be in a body of different sex.

It might be easier to understand what I am looking for if you consider this:

> You know how to drive a car and you have about 20 years of experience
> driving a MINI (or some other tiny car). One day your MINI is
> transformed into a family minivan with 3 rows of seats. You still can
> drive this minivan, you still can do it more or less safely. However,
> it *feels* different: Size, speed, acceleration, driver's seat, etc.
> The size feels too big or the vehicle feels too clumsy. The speed
> feels lacking. The acceleration is sluggish. The driver's seat is made
> of fabric and is cold making you grieve your old leather seats with
> heating. This new car is okay-ish but it just simply does not feel
> right.

---

**More notes** (in regard to opinion-based, unanswerable, etc.)

1. *Every person has a mental representation of their bodies - [body image](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-5583-7_403)*.
   As a mental construct, the original body image will be still present when a soul is placed into a new body. Since body image contains knowledge and expectations about the normal functioning of one's body a new body will inevitably create cognitive dissonance and disturbances in body image. Also, since the operation of one's body (with the exception of the automatic functions) consciously and unconsciously relies on body image a newly transported soul may face difficulties.
2. *This question is limited to sex differences in human physiology and their manifestation considering the disparity between the original body image and the new body*. The sex differences are relatively well understood and researched, they are limited in number. It is also possible to approximate (and for some of those differences it is even possible to calculate) the specific effects.
3. *For those who are confused by the wording 'how does it feel'*: Feel in the context of this question is not related to emotions but senses and physical experiences with the only exception of drastic physiological influence on emotions. I am not asking whether it will feel good or bad (that would be opinion-based), I am asking whether the person will feel out of balance due to differences in muscle and fat distribution and if so I ask to approximate how this out-of-balance condition will manifest from the body owner's point of view.
4. *Another reason for asking how does it feel is because I am a woman*. There are plenty of things that I do not know, do not understand, or would not even consider (see for example *Nosajimiki*'s answer) due to the fact that my own body is not male. Consider pregnancy, no matter how much you read about the biology of pregnancy or watch videos you would have no idea how it actually physically feels to be pregnant unless you were pregnant yourself or someone who has been pregnant shared their experiences with you.
5. *As for concerns about misgendering, invalidating, or questioning transgender identities, my question does not have anything to do with these topics*. I specifically stated that gender identity is out of the scope of this question.

---

If you need clarifications or additional details, please, ask in the comments.

Comment: When you say psychological differences are, are you saying all psychological differences, or just psychological issues with adjusting to their new gender role? Because physical differences in the neurological and endocrine systems could have a massive psychological impact.  To not feel these differences, you'd need to transplant the whole brain and several other female organs as part of the process.

Comment: @Nosajimiki In this question I do not want to touch psychology at all. I will ask for it in another question. For this question, I want to know how it literally feels to be in a body of different sex. Adjusting to a new gender role is out of the scope for both questions.

Comment: When "placed in a different body" there would be a lot of physiological issues related to different height/weight, different muscle/fat mass, different body proportions and metabolism. Many of those differences have little to do with XX vs XY difference. do you want to lest all of them, or only those directly related to primary sexual characteristics?

Comment: @Alexander Please assume that height/weight are approximately the same as the original female body. Other characteristics can be mentioned as long as they affect the perception of one's body and create cognitive dissonance or physical discomfort.

Comment: Are you looking for things like "Men have a higher centre of gravity. The transplantee will be less stable on their feet and fumble when doing agility exercises."?

Comment: Soul? if it done by magic then you decide what they do and do not notice. How much is the alteration is there to the neural network, can they see and hear right away or do they they have to relearn their sense organs like a transplant would require? Your going to have to tell us how much alteration she has undergone to mesh with the new body.

Comment: @Otkin You do realize that there are people in the real world who should be able to answer your questions. Do you know anybody in the trans community?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unanswerable. You are basing this question in the existence of a "soul" or a "conscience" which can be transplanted into a different body like you can change your car. But the analogy is not valid. You must use a steering wheel, and if you learnt to drive in an automatic you may struggle with the gears of a manual car, but I bet you don't know the name of all (if any) of the muscles you have used to type your question. While you can use transgender experiences and people with artificial limbs implanted as a guideline, all the answers here are POB.

Comment: Opinion-based. There is no way to qualify or quantify what differences someone would feel in this scenario, and inclusion of a 'soul' means all the physiological bases of identity are excluded, leaving *what* I'm not sure. Further I worry this exposes questioner and answerer to accusations of misgendering, invalidating, or questioning transgender identities.

Comment: This sounds like a difficult question, as according to all subjective evidence, Male and Female humans are actually completely different species, from different planets. Could you not ask something easier, like what it will feel like to have your mind put in a '68 vw Beetle? (Or even an actual Beetle, still closer to your native template)

Comment: Watch those stereotypes of gay men, please.

Comment: @Rekesoft I disagree with you. Every person has an image of their body. This image is mostly subconscious but it reflects the condition and performance of the body. If one's conscience or soul is placed into a different body a conflict between the existing body image and the actual new body is inevitable. This question asks for approximations of the consequences of this conflict. Considering that sex differences are well-known for humans, extrapolations based on this knowledge are not purely opinion-based. And answers provided demonstrate precisely this.

Comment: @Otkin The question is POB because an answer like "you would feel as if your new body had been always that way" is perfectly possible. There is no thing such a soul, a human person is a human body and if your body was a 192cm high, 96 kg of mostly muscle, you would move it with the same naturality that you move your current one. Because, you know, you don't consciently order every muscle of your body to move. You *just* do it. You would feel many differences, being a man, specially from other people - no more catcalling on the street - but there's no way to tell how you would *feel*.

Comment: @Rekesoft Are you suggesting that my question is POB because you do not accept the premise and ignore stated limitations and definitions?

Comment: @Otkin No, I accept your premise of exchanging conscience to a new body - that's a staple of sci-fi. Even if souls aren't real, you could go for "conscience", as in "Ghost in the shell" or "altered carbon". The point is that, intrinsically impossible as it is in a site such as worldbuilding.se, StackExchange tries to give "correct" answers to questions, and yours has no possible correct answer - or in other words, there are many possible answers and no way to determine which is the most correct one. The most we can offer you from here is "it would feel the way you want in your story". :)

Comment: @Rekesoft You keep ignoring stated definitions and limitations. Please make sure that you read the entire question and understand it well. If you need additional clarifications, feel free to request them.

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic worldbuilding query!, and I'd argue that there are plenty of avenues a respondent can go down that are not "opinion based". VTR.

Comment: VTO but I would change the title, replacing 2 words 'feel' and 'physiological' - first one is opinion based f-word trigger, and another one it took me 4 times(blind, non english native person) to read and after reading an answer I realised it a body thing and not a mind thing. Something like - female to male body swap, what difficulties at new home(due body differences) - just as an example

Comment: @MolbOrg When you cut your hand you feel pain. When you touch ice you feel cold. When you touch a hot stove you feel burn. These are objective physiological reactions. Feelings and emotions are not exactly the same.

Comment: @Otkin I do not argue about meaning of the word. Many words have a bundle of meanings, and there are multiple words for the same things, for reason, for reason sometimes we need them to remove ambiguety, sometimes for other reasons. It was just a feedback, wanna improve learn then think about it, do not need it - ignore. In both cases I gain no profit, almost.

Comment: @MolbOrg I get your idea. But I gave up on this question. Although, if it is reopened I will add a bounty (250 or 500 points).

Comment: Do not give up, lol, I still didn't gave up on mine, it can be reused as one of the tools of understanding situation on wb and part of introduce changes and detect them. As bounty it has very limited influence on quality of answers. Imho you got 90% or even a hundred of quality of answers which are possible atm on wb on your topic. WB is more about universality of topics, and there is a limit how deep they can be. As an example, power behing engeneering technology is quite weak atm, the only benefit that when asked here I do get some answers and in a more specialised place I get 0.

Comment: Look at this guy, [BackBack33](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/85994/backback33) , lol - 4 q's closed soon  to be 5 I guess, out of 5. And his q's seems to be quite poor at first glance, but they do make sense in some setting, he really could benefit from answers which tie things together in logical technology science way, and he would have quite solid and interesting foundation to develop for whatever he has in mind - fantasy work whatever

Answer (score 5):

> Basically, I want to know if walking, eating, talking, and other normal everyday activities will feel the same or will need some readjustment period.

Some adjustment period will most likely be needed. See also [this question](/questions/171644) and some of the answers thereto, the upshot of which is that if your body undergoes any sort of major change, there is most likely going to be some adjustment period. Or, simply consider the sometimes awkwardness of children and adolescents whose bodies are still changing on a daily basis.

Consider also motor problems experienced by people after an injury or period of inactivity. *Especially* consider the process by which amputees learn to control an artificial limb. A lot of the motor skills adults take for granted depend on practice and having a consistent "platform".

For that matter, even "some adjustment period" may be wildly optimistic. Unless you somehow arrange that all the nerve mappings are exactly the same between the two bodies, something like, say, a brain transplant would leave the poor sap starting *from scratch* in terms of motor control. Hopefully you at least got the autonomous functions right, or your victim isn't going to live very long, but even if (s)he does, (s)he may be starting with the (lack of) motor skill of a newborn. Actually, not even *that* much, since even newborns have had some time in the womb to practice.

> Will differences in hormonal status have noticeable physiological effects?

Absolutely; just ask anyone undergoing sex reassignment or taking hormone replacement therapy.

> I also wonder if the consummation of marriage is possible.

My guess would be "yes". Again, your best bet is to do some research into sex reassignment. Granted, I don't believe we've *demonstrated* this, but, well, in real life, someone that's undergone SRS is going to be missing "certain key parts", and there are some pretty hefty moral questions that would come into play if one were to try to find "donor parts". However, I'm not aware of any biological reason why this would be an issue.

---

Further thoughts in response to comments:

If your "female soul" (using quotes because we're now very much in hand-waving territory) isn't used to the mass of the male body, that's likely to be noticeable. Too, the male may have more muscle mass, and even if you assume the male body has similar mass to what the "female soul" expects, the ratios of muscle to fat are likely to be different. At the *very least*, your "female soul" is likely accustomed to a certain concentration of non-muscular tissue on her upper chest that is going to be missing.

I recommend finding some weights you can strap to your body and trying to move around; that should give you an example of the *minimum* sort of thing you might expect.

That all said... as soon as you say "the female soul and the male body are compatible" (or, just the fact that you're clearly employing some sort of hand-wavy process that can't be explained by hard science), it seems to me like you've crossed deep enough into "magic" territory that you could also hand-wave away — or *exaggerate* — such difficulties to whatever extent works for your story.

Comment: This is not a brain transplant surgery or something of a kind. The assumption is that the female soul and the male body are compatible and there are no big problems with body functions. Some things may feel weird or different, but everything works just fine. You make some good points. I wonder If you could supplement them with some examples.

Comment: Not just motor neurons, all the sensory signals will be different too, it is unlikely she will able to see or hear coherently for a while.

Comment: @Otkin souls don't exist, you are the pattern laid down in your brain, you can swap the brain or forcibly rewrite the pattern either way the problem is the same, the new pattern does not mesh with the existing one.

Comment: @John, that's not proven, and — especially for a story — that's imposing your own religion (yes, atheism is also a religion) onto someone else. Otkin's proposal AFAICT is well within willing suspension of disbelief for most people.

Comment: @Matthew its proven as much as anything in science is, Its no different than saying the the center of consciousness is not the liver and saying the stomach does not digest food by boiling it. both things people actually believed at one time. Or saying your kidneys function to purify blood and having a blood transfusion will not change your sex. . Also who mentioned religion? religion has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @John, no it isn't. We don't understand the brain well enough to say for certain that consciousness is a strictly chemical process, and we *definitely* don't understand where sapience comes from. Anyway, it's inappropriate to try to impose your religions beliefs (sorry, but Naturalism is absolutely a religion) on other people IRL; doubly so to try to impose them on an author's created world. If Otkin wants to write about a world where souls are real, or "gravity" is caused by the FSM's noodly appendages pressing down on everything, it is out of line for you to say otherwise.

Comment: @Matthew by your argument if I answer a worldbuilding question assuming a round planet I am imposing my religion on someone, unless the OP says otherwise the assumption is real world science applies.  You may not understand the brain well enough to by those who study it do. I can tell you which part of your brain you use to process numbers and do math, which part recognizes faces, and which part you use to stop yourself from doing something you want to do and don't want to do at the same time, you are your brain. Give me a rigorous definition of sapience and I will tell you were it comes from.

Comment: No, my argument is that if you answer a question about magic by asserting that magic doesn't exist, that's not appropriate. You are certainly free to apply your worldview in the absence of other information, but applying your worldview against a stated assumption would be, at best, a frame challenge. (And, yes, it would be inappropriate to tell Terry Pratchett that the world is round.)

Comment: @Matthew Thank you for the updates to your answer and comments. The premise indeed involves magic or some magic-like process that is left unexplained. I greatly appreciate your kindness and understanding of my question.

Comment: @John My premise does not even pretend to be scientific. It is magic. And I am trying to figure out the consequences of this magic.

Comment: @John Science can't explain what part of your brain is responsible for your contiguous   1st person existence.  It can explain what parts are responsible for processing experiences, and how they are processed, but by any scientific explanation, your ability to experience the world through your own body should not happen.  According to science, you are just a machine, but this only defines processes.  How one can BE a machine is thus far unexplained by any theory other than the existence of a soul. What a soul is may be misunderstood, but they are far from disproven.

Comment: @Nosajimiki what on earth makes you think a machine can't have a first person experience, a rat has a first person experience, any other experience, like meta-cognition, is harder to achieve. How you experience the world is not difficult to explain at all, you are a processor for sensory data that models the world around, this also includes a model of yourself and a model of other minds. More importantly a soul is not an explanation, it is just moving the goalposts, unless you think you have a detailed explanation of how an undefined soul achieves it that can't also be applied to a brain.

Comment: @Otkin if the magic-like process is unexplained, we cannot possibly predict how it will behave - the best we can is to draw parallels with a similar process that is relatively understood. And while we can't rule out the possibility of having overlooked something important, the current model does not leave any discrepancies open. Neural networks are just  that powerful - and we've only been using feed-forward networks in ANN apllications. Application-specific recursive feedback networks must be even more powerful if only we had the hardware to actually run them..

Comment: @John, "soul" is hand-waving for something *we can't explain at this time*. Perhaps we will eventually prove "souls" don't exist. Perhaps we will prove that they *do*. We don't know. Meanwhile, it is no less unscientific to assume that they *must not* exist as to assume that they do.

Comment: @John You are mistaking stimulus-response with a first person experience.  All we can observe in machines (or other people) is a third person experience.  Sure, we understand the aspects of a brain that make it a stimulus-response machine, but what you can not explain with known science is why you are you, and not me or the toaster.  While you can assume to a degree that other people have 1st person experiences b/c you have them and we are like you, you do not know where they come from.  So, assuming you can create them just by making a stimulus-response machine is a leap of faith, not science

Comment: Although, it is also possible that you do not understand me because you do not not actually have a first person experience.  I could in theory be the one being in all of existence to have a true first person experience, in which case, it is me who is making too many assumptions, but I'm pretty sure I have enough in common with other people that that which I am would be similar to what others like me are.

Answer (score 4):

### Most of your issues will be hormonal and neurological in nature.

Before you downvote for delving into psychology, it is important to know that psychology and neurology are two different things. If you think of your mind as a computer system, your psychology is the software of your mind, and your neurology is the hardware. While software may try to function the same when installed on two different computers, differences in CPU, GPU, RAM, HD, etc. can cause the software to function very differently, even if it is the same program.  The same would be true trying to run one person's mind in another person's body.

The the most noticable difference between the male and female brain is the size of the [corpus callosum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_callosum). A female corpus callosum allows one to hold onto multiple thoughts at a time, transition between thoughts more easily, and associate emotions with logical thoughts better.  The male corpus callosum allows one to stay more focused on the task at hand because it creates a weaker connection between emotional and logical processes and is less prone to distractions.  The closest experience a woman might have to this prior to the switch would be like taking ADHD medications, or having a mid-brain concussion.

On this level, the woman may find herself feeling trapped inside her own mind, she will be aware of the thoughts she is having, but struggle to express them.  She will also likely have feelings that you might describe as "dead inside" because she will no longer be able to process her emotional state the way she is used to.  An alternative consequence is that her female software may try pushing it's normal amount of traffic between hemispheres which would make her feel more normal but put her at a major risk for seizures.

For hormonal differences, we all know that she will have more testosterone and less estrogen meaning that she will be more prone to bouts of aggression, right?  Not necessarily.  As it turns out, [estrogen is the hormone responsible for human aggression](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S009130220500049X), and [testosterone therapy is often used in women to decrease the anxiety, irritability and aggression associated with PMS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378512213000121).  Her endocrine system will push her into a more relaxed, emotionally level state of being than she is probably used to. Between this and the corpus callosum, she will probably feel something comparable to [getting stoned](https://weedmaps.com/learn/cannabis-and-its-evolution/stoned#:%7E:text=stoned%20is%20when%20you%20experience%20the%20relaxed,%20sedative%20effects%20of%20consuming%20marijuana), and it will probably take at least a few weeks if not months before she her new reality starts to feel normal to her... assuming it does not trigger any secondary psychological issues like chronic depression.

#### Kinesiological differences would be minor, but existent

Balance may be a bit of an issue but not for the reasons most people have cited so far.  If you've ever put on a backpack or carried a thing that weighs more than a few kilos, you already know that your body is very good at adjusting to distribution of weight issues. The only reason balance would be all that hard is because a woman's pelvis is shaped differently.  A woman's legs are turned slightly more outward from a man's so, this will affect her gait.  This difference would be more pronounced if the woman has had kids.

Men also have slightly longer arms than women for their height.  So, even if the male body is as tall as the female body, she will probably enjoy a slightly longer reach.  I say "enjoy" loosely here, because at first it could be off putting.  Her Eye-hand coordination would be fine because it relies on the biofeedback of seeing what your hands are doing while you do it, but proprioception based coordination would be difficult because this relies on intuitively knowing where your hand is in space.  Children often experience several weeks of clumsiness after major growth spurts of several inches or more; so, your woman may have a similar experience here, but in general, the differences in arm length are just small enough, I don't think it would be overly noticeable.

... then there are those things that guys don't really like to talk about, but I will bring them up anyways because they are scientifically relevant here: *her new found gonads will get in the way*.  A man who knows his own body walks in a certain way that he does not hurt himself, but sometimes men have one of those off days where they literally just walk wrong over too long of a distance and thier tessicals start to hurt. Does not happen to guys very often, but a woman who does not know how to walk with something there is much more likely to struggle with it for a while.  Then there is that other thing called "ball-stickage" where you sweat a little and they stick to your leg.  If you've ever seen a man walking and he just randomly steps with a single wide step, or kicks out to one side a bit, that is him removing his balls from the side of his leg. To a man this is a normal occurrence, but to woman, I'd imagine it would be a very concerning experience... especially if she decides to go with boxers instead of briefs.

Also, differences in body strength will not really be all that apparent for most of what she does unless she tries pushing herself beyond normal daily activities.  99% of the day is spent doing things that any woman would be able to do without really trying that hard anyway. There would just be that occasional moment for a while where she realizes she can open that stumborn pickle jar... these would be novel experiences for her but not really require much of an adjustment period.

Eating and talking would be different, but not require a significant adjustment period.  The transition from gender nonspecific to male specific vocal structures is a pretty spontaneous change that happens in adolescent boys.  Despite this, most boys do not even notice it has happened until someone else points it out to them; so, I would not imagine this being an issue to physically adjust to, it would just be a bit different.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting a lot of thought into it and especially the points about men walking habits. This is, indeed, something that people rarely talk about.

Comment: Good answer, interesting. As dongles are involved, hey where famous sitting posture, also laying  and(or) sleeping one as well(basicaĺly the same stuff to avoid pressure, which not necessarly leads to noticing it immediatly, most irritating part about it actually, but may have  consequences)

Comment: @MolbOrg Ah yes, the good old sitting with your legs spread.  I imagine she will hurt herself a few times trying to sit down too quickly before she learns... and if she has a good sense of humor about it she will exclaim "... and I oop" every time.

Answer (score 3):

Necessary disclaimer that I'm not an expert and the following speculations are based off of personal research.

Like any old soul in a new body, she would have to adjust herself to the physique. She'd likely be taller than before, and with longer limbs, which really won't cause more than the occasional clumsiness unless the difference is drastic. If she has the same muscle mass as before, her body may feel slightly heavier to move and use. If she has *proportionately* the same amount of muscle mass, she'll have to get used to being a little stronger, which means for a bit she may grip things too hard or push things too far, etc. **So from a physical perspective, all the normal side effects that come with having a new body and getting used to that, and being clumsy while you still figure it out.**

On a more chemistry side of things, she's going to have **more testosterone**, which comes with effects like a higher sex drive, increased bone strength, higher metabolism, and gaining muscle mass more easily. She'll have **less estrogen**, which means less serotonin (the happy stuff) and more mood swings. Mens bodies also collect visceral fat (unhealthy fat) more than subcutaneous fat (good fat), which means they're **more prone to health conditions like diabetes and heart disease, and their blood sugar levels change less easily than womens.** How does all of this make her feel? She may have more energy day to day, but her mental health will be more fragile and moody. She might be surprised at how quickly she loses weight and gains muscle (if she exercises), and of course, the higher sex drive.

Psychologically, (the biological effects on the brain, since you said not to mention the mental effects), **I'm not sure if there are really any differences in the way a man and a women think.** To my knowledge, this area is still inconclusive. Some say women are instinctively more social and "motherly", however research suggests this is likely *societal conditioning rather than biology*.

A few more notes on the behavioral aspect of things, she'll likely be acutely aware of her new reproductive system for a while, as she'll be used to her old physique. The lack of weight on her chest and the new weight on her hips may feel uncomfortable. In my personal experience as well, women tend to hold their backs slightly arched compared to men, and stand with their feet closer together. She may continue to adopt these tendencies in her new body. Also, if her body was pretty curvy before, she'll be unused to the new, straighter body shape, which'll be especially apparent when she puts on/takes off clothes.

Comment: "She'll likely be acutely aware of her new reproductive system for a while" +100 . ("New"? "For a while"? Seriously, how many guys aren't "acutely aware" of their "reproductive system" *more often than not*?)

Comment: I wouldn't know, I'm a woman ahaha. But I know if I had a new reproductive system it would weird me out for a looong time. I don't know if I would ever get used to it, or get over having a flat chest 

Comment: If it lasts for more than 3 months, then she is "chronically" aware of her new reproductive system.

Comment: @Matthew I am with cassidia.68 on this. I am also a woman and I would probably have an even more exaggerated reaction to a sudden appearance of something unexpected between my legs.

Comment: @Otkin, well, sure . I didn't mean the character wouldn't have a reaction, perhaps stronger initially, it was more the implication that this reaction would go away over time I, ah, disagree with. The "OMG!!!?!" factor may fade, but *awareness* — yes, sometimes "acute" — won't fully go away. (Not if the body isn't impotent, at least.)

Comment: @Matthew I’m a guy and I disagree. For the majority of the day, I am not more aware of it than my limbs. I wear boxers so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @Blue, to be fair, my statement was something of a comic hyperbole (the "joke" is explicitly making reference to the "guys are *always* horny" stereotype). There is, however, some truth in it in that many males *do* experience physical arousal, and thus periods of "acute awareness" (particularly if wearing snug-fitting clothing), on a fairly regular bases.

Comment: @Matthew Oh yes I agree. I was just disagreeing with "more often than not".

Answer (score 3):

**Addendum**

Other answers have covered most changes. My understanding is that cutting very long hair will have a similar effect (mass change, apparent muscle performance) to many changes. Not having to relearn speech implies that walking will be automatic, but one's choice of path is related to one's perceived dimensions (and politeness).

However, this leaves two considerations - familiar nerves/functions which no longer exist/map to anything in this body, and nerves/functions which now exist and don't map to anything familiar.

**Missing structures**: The mind seems likely to experience phantom-limb syndrome to some extent. It is also possible that these nerves expected by the mind will be re-mapped to equivalent areas.

**New structures**: The mind will have difficulty in interpreting any sensation, and is likely to initially have trouble associating nerves with locations. (Ever tried to scratch an itch which moves? Your brain doesn't usually need to know which nerves are affected, since most things affect the whole area.) Assuming that the mind is not adverse to testing, it's likely that they'll take some time to prod different nerves, to learn what sensation corresponds to what location.

**Sex organs**: You specifically mention this in your question, but the scenario you describe is an idealised test-case for many arguments. Opinions on how much control over these is possible vary, as do the implications for marriage (legal or religious). Individual psychology is a significant factor, and opinions are divided on how much influence the mind has over reflexive attraction.

**A baseline**: it is possible to influence when an arousal response to occur, but the response is at least semi-autonomous (ex: can occur while asleep). This means that it may occur when unprompted/unwanted, and is likely to occur when prompted/wanted. The exact nature of your transfer will influence the nerve-correspondence between the old and new body, and hence how 'familiar' the mind finds it, but broadly-equivalent structures exist. Physical differences will lead to a degree of adjustment being necessary. However, this may also prompt a more detailed understanding and a greater degree of control.

(Disclaimer: Fish scales are broadly equivalent to hairs, in that they form from the same embryonic structure. This is *another* area where reams of discussion might be written.)

Comment: Comments for other answers suggest that many males have a semi-continuous conscious awareness of their reproductive biology (presumably not the internal elements). Previous conversations I've had suggest that this is cultural/psychological rather than biological, but it's possible that I've drawn a non-representative sample.

Comment: Rather, are you continuously semi-aware of your arm? Or your foot? Certain male parts, being external, are (depending on clothing) subject to near-constant stimuli. (Yes, there is some degree of "guys are *always* horny", but it also has to do with physical exposure and that said parts are often being bumped or jostled, or are *itching*.) OTOH, my own personal experience is not a representative sample, and something as basic as a guy that wears boxers may make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

You might be best to study the experience of woman who  Have transitioned to trans men.  Your story is  Not identical to thier but there is similarities .
Basically she will have to deal with a sudden increase in strength, Bone density and size.  Many of these changes occur in woman transitioning.

Something to consider:
Is her new body attracted to men? A lot of attraction is  Psychological but certainly not all of it  Physiology also plays any important part.

Comment: The key point here is that changing the body will change the "mind" indirectly. For example the new body will produce different levels of testosterone/estrogen/cortisol/adrenaline and the hundreds of other hormones that regulate mood on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: I was considering this, but I ultimately came to a conclusion that the experiences of transgender individuals who transitioned are not applicable. Two main reasons are: 1) Even after the full transition the body is still the original body; 2) the transition is a gradual process while in my case the change is immediate. There is no adjustment period, no preparation, no expectations. I am also not sure if transitioned XX body is sufficiently close to the native XY body. I am not a specialist in this topic, so my words might not be clear enough. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Otkin The experience will be similar in some ways and different in others.

Comment: Trans men do not actually gain/loose all of their female inner workings.  While hormone therapy can cause some changes in an adult, many aspects of the human body can only form during specific developmental phases of your life.